# How to solve the following linear programming problem using Gurobi (or at least python)?

Tags: linear-programming, python, gurobi

For an optional ungraded assignment (see it as a complex problem that won't be graded, more to test our skills and knowledge) I was given the following problem. It is not as straightforward as all the other examples we covered and I would really like to know how to solve the problem.

A hotel is estimating that in the next 7 days they will need to have available the following number of sheets:

| Day | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sheet demand | 20 | 15 | 30 | 40 | 45 | 45 | 15 |

Starting day 1 they have 0 sheets. They need to buy sheets at $20 per set and they can wash to reuse. There are 2 types of laundry services:

$6 requiring 2 days (sheets can be used on day 1 and then again on day 3)

$3 requiring 3 days (sheets can be used on day 1 and then again on day 4)

The question:

How can I formulate the linear programming model to determine the optimal laundry and purchasing policy? And how can I run this using Gurobi (Python)?

All I know up to now is that I need to minimize *costs of buying, cheap and luxury laundry*. Lets say buy = b_i and ranges from 1-7, luxury = x_i and ranges from 1-5 and cheap = y_ij and ranges from (1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7 , 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.6, 3.7 and 4.7), other than that I do not know how to go further.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE! To get an answer, it's best to show your work and ask specific questions about where you're stuck.

Comment: That's just it. I am not much farther than this. I guess I do know that I need to minimize costs of buying, cheap and luxury laundry. Lets say buy = b_i and ranges from 1-7, luxury = x_i and ranges from 1-5 and cheap = y_ij and ranges from (1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7 , 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.6, 3.7 and 4.7).
other than that I do not know.

Comment: @Simba63, it sounds like a varients of the lot-sizing problem. Do you see/try that?

Comment: @A.Omidi I have not heard of it yet and will gladly take a look. An initial google search brings up a paper by Tempelmeijer & Hilger. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Simna63, I thik you would need to define the variable clearly such that you can develop an initial mathematical model. For example, define the positive variable $x_i$ to represent the number of luxury and, etc. What you mean by defining the index $i$ and $j$?

Comment: Ah yes sorry that wasnt clear. What I meant was for the cheap laundry: if you get it washed on day 1 you have the option of using it on 4, 5, 6 or 7 and so further for day 2, 3 and 4. This is of course the cheapest option so you would want to use this option the most.

Answer (score 1):

- A) For each day for each required sheet, make an optimization variable that decides whether to do expensive or cheap laundry after using it that day.
- B) Don't make the "sheets to buy" a genuine optimization variable. Simply buy the number of missing sheets every day. Let's call that a shadow variable `sheetsToBuy`.
- C) For each day, add a shadow variable `availableSheets` to calculate the number of sheets available to use that day, before buying extra. So if `requiredSheets > availableSheets`, then `sheetsToBuy = requiredSheets - availableSheets`. Calculation for `availableSheets = previousday.availableSheets - (previousday.requiredSheets - previousDay.sheetsToBuy) + day.sheetsReturningFromLaundry`.
- D) That `sheetsReturningFromLaundry` is calculated based on the
  optimization variables from A). Basically the number of expensive laundry decisions 2 days ago plus the number of cheap laundry decisions 3 days ago.